# CSS. Rotated image on the mobile screens

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

http://jsfiddle.net/ajxqnqpo/

I have rotated image (it should be rotated with css). I need to display it on the full screen for any type of mobile devices (so I can't use fixed width and fixed margin here). And image should have 10px margin from each side.

I can't do it, because rotate function is added invisible gap for image sides (left and right). You can see this effect on the jsfiddle, image is not sticked to the left border of screen.

Any ideas how this can be done? Thanks

```
<div>
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/sakTcZr.jpg" />
</div>

img {
    -moz-transform:rotate(-90deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(-90deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(-90deg);
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
```

Comment: the size of the image is calculated before rotation

Comment: I'd reccomend using a media query and a different version of the image already rotated to fit 100% width and height. Then just add your margin of 10 pixels. Anything under 660px for the query should do. If your not familiar check media queries out here: https://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/

Answer (score 1):

I changed ur fiddle now it rotates at smaller devices.
Just change the size of your HTML fiddle screen and you can the effect.

Solution:

```
   @media (max-width: 767px) {
        img{
         -moz-transform:rotate(-90deg);
        -webkit-transform:rotate(-90deg);
        -ms-transform:rotate(-90deg);
        transform: rotate(-90deg);   
        }
    }
```